# install navigation form sources

Tags: ros, navigation, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,I have installed the Groovy Ros-Comm from source. Now,I need the navigation package.So I download the navigation source code from Browse Software http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php. At the same time, I download all the packages that navigation depends ,and put them in the navigation.I compiled the navigation using rosmake.Than it shows as following:

error: /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/include/robot_pose_ekf/nonlinearanalyticconditionalgaussianodo.h:22:59: did not have pdf/analyticconditionalgaussian_additivenoise.h：
In fact,there is the  file at bfl/src/.I have download the bfl and put it in the navigation package.

PS: I can not install navigation through `sudo apt-get install navigation`
Please help me.How can I install navigation from source.What causes this error.How to solve it.Thank you very much.

```
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                   
    [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['navigation-groovy-devel']                                     
    [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['navigation-groovy-devel']                                                   
    [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sxl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141127-143344                            
    [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['navigation-groovy-devel'] to:
    ['bondcpp', 'bond', 'smclib', 'bondpy', 'test_bond', 'bfl', 'voxel_grid', 'flann', 'pcl_ros', 'nav_core', 'nodelet', 'move_base_msgs', 'pcl', 'dwa_local_planner', 'clear_costmap_recovery', 'move_slow_and_clear', 'base_local_planner', 'rotate_recovery', 'amcl', 'map_server', 'fake_localization', 'robot_pose_ekf', 'move_base', 'laser_geometry', 'nodelet_topic_tools', 'test_nodelet_topic_tools', 'test_nodelet', 'navfn', 'tf_conversions', 'kdl_conversions', 'eigen_conversions', 'tf', 'costmap_2d', 'carrot_planner', 'pcl_msgs']
    [rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                          
    [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                         
    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
     No Makefile in package bondcpp                   
    [rosmake-2] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                                                               
    [rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl_conversions [ make ]                                                                                                                                       
            
            ………………                                                                                                           
    [rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                                                        
    [rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
     No Makefile in package std_srvs                
    [rosmake-3] Starting >>> amcl [ make ]                                                                            
    [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbot_pose_ekf: 4.3 sec ] [ costmap_2d: 4.2 sec ] [ actionli... [ 4 Active 69/82 Complete ]
    {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          vals = rospack.get_depends(package, implicit=True)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 227, in get_depends
          s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 227, in get_depends
          s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 227, in get_depends
          s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 227, in get_depends
          s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 227, in get_depends
          s.update(self.get_depends(p, implicit))
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 221, in get_depends
          names = [p.name for p in self.get_manifest(name).depends]
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 159, in get_manifest
          return self._load_manifest(name)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 198, in _load_manifest
          retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 190, in get_path
          raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
      rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: cmake_modules
      ROS path [0]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/install_isolated/share/ros
      ROS path [1]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel
      ROS path [2]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/slam_gmapping
      ROS path [3]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-1.8.3
      ROS path [4]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/common_rosdeps
      ROS path [5]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/pluginlib
      ROS path [6]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/visualization_msgs
      ROS path [7]=/home/sxl/actionlib
      ROS path [8]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/install_isolated/share
      ROS path [9]=/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/install_isolated/stacks
      
      CMake Error at /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/install_isolated/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:78 (string):
        string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/install_isolated/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:99 (gencfg_cpp)
        CMakeLists.txt:21 (include)
      
      
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package costmap_2d written to:
    [ rosmake ]    /home/sxl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141127-143344/costmap_2d/build_output.log
    [rosmake-2] Finished <<< costmap_2d [FAIL] [ 4.22 seconds ]                                                       
    [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package costmap_2d. 
    [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.     
    [rosmake-3] Finished <<< amcl [PASS] [ 3.36 seconds ]                                                             
    [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbot_pose_ekf: 7.3 sec ] [ actionlib: 4.3 sec ]                [ 2 Active 70/82 Complete ]
    {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [ 57%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
      make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      [ 57%] Built target rospack_gensrv
      make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      [ 57%] Built target rospack_genmsg
      make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      [ 57%] Built target rospack_gensrv_all
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      [ 57%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
      [ 57%] make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      Built target rospack_genmsg_all
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[3]: 正在进入目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      [ 71%] [ 85%] [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/nonlinearanalyticconditionalgaussianodo.cpp.o
      Building CXX object CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp.o
      Building CXX object CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/odom_estimation.cpp.o
      In file included from /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/src/nonlinearanalyticconditionalgaussianodo.cpp:18:0:
      /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/include/robot_pose_ekf/nonlinearanalyticconditionalgaussianodo.h:22:59: 致命错误： pdf/analyticconditionalgaussian_additivenoise.h：没有那个文件或目录
      编译中断。
      In file included from /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/src/odom_estimation.cpp:37:0:
      /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/include/robot_pose_ekf/odom_estimation.h:40:41: 致命错误： filter/extendedkalmanfilter.h：没有那个文件或目录
      编译中断。
      make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/odom_estimation.cpp.o] 错误 1
      make[3]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
      make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/nonlinearanalyticconditionalgaussianodo.cpp.o] 错误 1
      In file included from /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/include/robot_pose_ekf/odom_estimation_node.h:44:0,
                       from /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp:37:
      /home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/include/robot_pose_ekf/odom_estimation.h:40:41: 致命错误： filter/extendedkalmanfilter.h：没有那个文件或目录
      编译中断。
      make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp.o] 错误 1
      make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/robot_pose_ekf.dir/all] 错误 2
      make[2]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
      make[1]: *** [all] 错误 2
      make[1]:正在离开目录 `/home/sxl/ros_catkin_ws1/src/navigation-groovy-devel/robot_pose_ekf/build'
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    [ rosmake ] Output from build of package robot_pose_ekf written to:
    [ rosmake ]    /home/sxl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141127-143344/robot_pose_ekf/build_output.log
    [rosmake-1] Finished <<< robot_pose_ekf [FAIL] [ 7.39 seconds ]                                                   
    [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package robot_pose_ekf. 
    [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. 
    [rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib [PASS] [ 7.03 seconds ]                                                        
    [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                              
    [ rosmake ] Built 73 packages with 2 failures.                                                                    
    [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198428/install-navigation-form-sources/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're doing so many things wrong.. I don't even..

1. You don't state which version of ROS you're using or which OS you're using.
2. Don't use rosbuild in a catkin workspace. At this point, almost all of ROS is using catkin; there shouldn't be any need to use rosbuild at all.
3. Why are you checking out ros_comm from source? That's a pretty serious modification to ROS, and you don't give any reason for actually needing to do so. Downgrading the version of ros_comm that you're using to one from an older version of ROS is a highly likely to introduce bugs and incompatibilities.
4. Groovy is no longer supported, You should probably be using a newer version of ROS.

As stated on the [installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1), ROS packages are prefixed with `ros-` and the distro name. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-navigation
```

Or, if you're still using Groovy:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-navigation
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-12-01**:
@ahendrix    Because I have installed ros-groovy ros-comm on ubuntu12.04 on armel. You have ever told me that it no longer support armel. So I install ros-comm from source.But now I need the navigation  package.I have downloaded the navigation and the relevant package.

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-12-01**:
@ahendrix   When I compile the navigation it shows there are not the file of `bfl`.In fact,I have downloaded the bfl packages,and put it in the navigation packages

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
You **REALLY** need to mention things like your ROS version, OS and your architecture in the question; otherwise I assume that you're using a standard installation of a recent version of ROS on Ubuntu x86.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
navigation is a dry (rosbuild) package on groovy, and bfl is a wet (catkin) package. You should have separate catkin and rosbuild workspaces. navigation and other dry packages should be in the rosbuild workspace, and bfl and other wet packages should be in the dry workspace.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-01**:
You should build and source your wet (catkin) workspace before attempting to build your dry (rosbuild) workspace.